# Stop irrelevant log from Bluetooth's GKSession?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, gksession

How to stop the following code when `GKSession` starts search?

```
 BTM: posting notification BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:05.666 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: Adding new device 0x110db0 Jahangir Nawaz’s iPhone 00:23:DF:3C:BC:5B 0xf5210003
2011-05-17 20:25:05.669 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0xffffffff eventType = 0 event = 0 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:06.406 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 1 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:06.466 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 11 result = 305
2011-05-17 20:25:06.491 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: received BT_SERVICE_CONNECT event type with 0 currently connected services
2011-05-17 20:25:06.494 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothDeviceConnectFailedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:07.467 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: received BT_LOCAL_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STATUS_CHANGED event
2011-05-17 20:25:07.469 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothConnectionStatusChangedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:11.571 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0xffffffff eventType = 0 event = 0 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:12.576 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 1 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:13.581 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 11 result = 305
2011-05-17 20:25:13.590 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: received BT_SERVICE_CONNECT event type with 0 currently connected services
2011-05-17 20:25:13.591 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothDeviceConnectFailedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:14.587 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: received BT_LOCAL_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STATUS_CHANGED event
2011-05-17 20:25:14.589 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothConnectionStatusChangedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:15.594 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0xffffffff eventType = 0 event = 0 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:16.598 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 1 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:17.604 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 11 result = 305
2011-05-17 20:25:17.613 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: received BT_SERVICE_CONNECT event type with 0 currently connected services
2011-05-17 20:25:17.614 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothDeviceConnectFailedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:18.611 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: received BT_LOCAL_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STATUS_CHANGED event
2011-05-17 20:25:18.613 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothConnectionStatusChangedNotification
2011-05-17 20:25:19.618 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0xffffffff eventType = 0 event = 0 result = 0
2011-05-17 20:25:20.624 BLUConnect[2120:307] BTM: _btServiceEventCallback: service = 0x800 eventType = 0 event = 1 result = 0
```

Comment: Arrgh! I know, how annoying are they?!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is within Apple's lib, it seems that there is no direct way of switching it off - I would submit a "bug" ticket ...

I'm pretty sure, that it is not possible to overload/overwrite the NSLog method in order to avoid those logs.

May I ask whether there is a specific need for switching this off?

Greetings,
matthias

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.  The logs happen automatically do to the methods apple give you to create and use GKSessions.  I can't see any legitimate reason for NEEDING to switch them off other than to reduce clutter in your console.

Cheers,
Sidd